# Subdomain answer to specific folder in Apache

Tags: apache, dns, apache2, apache2.2, apache2.4

I want to configure an Apache vhost. Practically Basically I want by typing the address files.yyyyyy.ltd answer me the folder destination /var/www/html/alpha/files

This is apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alpha/files
        ServerName files.yyyyyy.ltd
        ServerAlias files.yyyyyy.ltd
        <Directory /var/www/html/alpha/files >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        # Other directives here
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS configuration:

```
yyyyyy.ltd.  IN A      XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www          IN CNAME  yyyyyy.ltd.
yyyyyy.ltd.  IN CNAME  files.yyyyyy.ltd.
```

What is wrong? Do you recommend some other method to achieve the same result?

Thk for help

Answer (score 0):

#### DNS configuration

you need to change

```
yyyyyy.ltd.  IN CNAME  files.yyyyyy.ltd.
```

to

```
files  IN CNAME  yyyyyy.ltd.
```

you can also set all as A record like

```
yyyyyy.ltd.        IN A      XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www.yyyyyy.ltd.    IN A      XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 
files.yyyyyy.ltd.  IN  A     XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

What i would do to have a faster name resolution.

#### Apache configuration

Your Apache configuration is correct, but some stuffs are useless:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alpha/files
        ServerName files.yyyyyy.ltd
        <Directory /var/www/html/alpha/files >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        # Other directives here
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`AllowOverride all` is there to allow .htaccess, if you don't want .htaccess files, you can remove this command from your configuration.